# shorting algorithm to convert with star (*) Python

Tags: python, sorting

A function named `fungsiIO`, which has no input argument, to change input from user as integer which seperated with space to print stars (*) character. those star are sorted from the smallest (top) to the largest (down)

Note: only once input command/ input function.

---

My Code:

```
def fungsiIO():
    pass
    #????
```

---

Run/invoke function:

```
fungsiIO() # example input 7 4 5 3 1 2
```

---

input and expected output:

```
7 4 5 3 1 2
*
**
***
****
*****
*******
```

---

Thank you very much for anyone who help me

Comment: python 3 or 2 ?

Comment: ``My code``, where is the code don't see any thing !!

Comment: in python 3, ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

```
def fungsiIO():
    numbers = set(map(int, input().split())) 
    # if you enter 7 4 5 3 1 2 then
    # numbers will be {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}, sorted and all unique.

    for num in numbers:
        print("*"*num,end='')
        print()


fungsiIO()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sorted()` this will sort your numbers in ascending order.

You can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted)

```py
def sol(nums):
    for i in sorted(nums):
        print("*"*i,end='')
        print()

sol([7,4,5,3,1,2])
```

#### Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
*******
```